# How to use Serializer and Deserializer in Sagemaker 2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I spin up a Sagemaker notebook using the `conda_python3` kernel, and follow the [example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/random_cut_forest/random_cut_forest.ipynb) Notebook for [Random Cut Forest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/randomcutforest.html).

As of this writing, the [Sagemaker SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) that comes with `conda_python3` is version 1.72.0, but I want to use new features, so I update my notebook to use the latest

```py
%%bash
pip install -U sagemaker
```

And I see it updates.

```py
print(sagemaker.__version__)

# 2.4.1
```

A change from version 1.x to 2.x was the [serializer/deserializer classes](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v2.html#serializer-and-deserializer-classes)

Previously (in version 1.72.0) I'd update my predictor to use the proper serializer/deserializer, and could run inference on my model

```py
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer, json_deserializer


rcf_inference = rcf.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
)

rcf_inference.content_type = 'text/csv'
rcf_inference.serializer = csv_serializer
rcf_inference.accept = 'application/json'
rcf_inference.deserializer = json_deserializer

results = rcf_inference.predict(some_numpy_array)
```

(Note this all comes from the [example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/random_cut_forest/random_cut_forest.ipynb)

I try and replicate this using sagemaker 2.4.1 like so

```py
from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer
from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer

rcf_inference = rcf.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
    serializer=CSVSerializer,
    deserializer=JSONDeserializer
)

results = rcf_inference.predict(some_numpy_array)
```

And I receive an error of

```
TypeError: serialize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

I know I'm using the serliaizer/deserializer incorrectly, but can't find good documentation on how this should be used

Answer (score 19, accepted):

in order to use the new serializers/deserializers, you will need to init them, for example:

```
from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer
from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer

rcf_inference = rcf.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
    serializer=CSVSerializer(),
    deserializer=JSONDeserializer()
)
```

Comment: Dude!! You are awesome!! This worked for my usecase as well

Comment: Didnt work for me. No errors but returned output is not in json format. Prediction output is in numpy array inspite of deserializer=JSONDeserializer()

Answer (score 3):

In the case of a custom Serializer we can do it this way in SageMaker 2.x:

```py
from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer
from sagemaker.serializers import JSONSerializer


class FMSerializer(JSONSerializer):
    def serialize(self, data):
        js = {'instances': []}
        for row in data:
            js['instances'].append({'features': row.tolist()})
        return json.dumps(js)


predictor = estimator.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge",
    serializer=FMSerializer(),
    deserializer=JSONDeserializer()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer

xgb_predictor.content_type = 'text/csv' # set the data type for an inference

xgb_predictor.serializer = CSVSerializer() # set the serializer type

predictions = xgb_predictor.predict(x_test).decode('utf-8') # predict!
predictions_array = np.fromstring(predictions[1:], sep=',') # and turn the prediction into an array
print(predictions_array.shape)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).